# Custom Validator: IsValid is not called when using overloaded method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, validation

If I do the following:

```
public class CustomRangeAttribute : RangeAttribute
{
    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        return base.IsValid(value);
    }
}
```

The method is executed as expected.
If I do:

```
protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
{
   return base.IsValid(value, validationContext);
}
```

The method is not called. Why?
sl3dg3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works exactly as you'd expect if you are using ASP.NET MVC **3.0**.  I tried it myself using your example and it works great -- I get a non-null ValidationContext and it does get invoked.  See [here](http://blog.devlpr.net/2010/07/27/asp-net-mvc-3-new-features-in-preview-1/) for a full elaboration on this.  So this suggests yet another reason (beyond the awesome Razor engine) to upgrade to v.3.0.

Comment: Hmmm... do I have a chance to retreive `ValidationContext` somehow if I don't inherit from `ValidationAttribute`?

Comment: @sl3dg3, it doesn't look like it.  `ValidationContext` is only available when the validation goes through the `GetValidationResult` method.  I suspect for MVC it's not going that route.  Out of curiosity, what data did you want to pull from `ValidationContext`?

Comment: I wanted to get some information about the property where the attribute is used on: `if (validationContext.ObjectType.IsArray) {...}`

Comment: @sl3dg3, after further research, I've realized that this *is* supported.  Please see my updated answer.

Comment: very cool, thx for checking. Indeed, now I am really supposed to upgrade to v3 :-)

Comment: Strange I am getting the same problem as the OP on MVC4