# Validation Context is always NULL?

Tags: c#, validation, asp.net-mvc-3, data-annotations

I have custom validation attribute such as this:

```
    public class MyCustomAttribute : ValidationAttribute {
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext) {
        if ((int)value == 100) {
            // do some checking to validate & return ValidationResult accordingly

        } else return ValidationResult.Success;
    }
}
```

In usage like this:

```
    [DisplayName("My Custom Property")]
    [MyCustom(ErrorMessage = "ERROR!!!")]
    public int? MyCustomProperty { get; set; }
```

My question is: why is it that inside MyCustomAttribute, within the IsValid method, validationContext is always NULL? Is there anything special I need to set to get it not to be NULL?

Comment: I realize you state that you are, but my understanding is that this is an MVC 3.0 feature.  You're absolutely sure you're on MVC 3.0?

Comment: By default there is nothing special you have to do to get it to work.

Comment: OK - for some odd reason, it revert back to the 2.0 ref (instead of sticking to the 3.0 ref). I got it working now with MVC 3.0 (as intended). *sigh.

Comment: @Kirk if you write your post/comment as an answer, I will mark it as the accepter answer.

Comment: @Johannes, that feels dirty. :)  I think I'll just mark it as a dup (since now that we know you weren't using 2.0, it *is*).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Custom Validator: IsValid is not called when using overloaded method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5235101/custom-validator-isvalid-is-not-called-when-using-overloaded-method)

Answer (score 3):

if you use

```
ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
```

to check if data is valid you have to use

```
v.GetValidationResult(propertyValue,new ValidationContext(this))!= ValidationResult.Success
```

instead of

```
 v.IsValid(propertyValue)
```

Comment: What does `v` represent here?

Answer (score 2):

### you must override RequiresValidationContext

---

`public override bool RequiresValidationContext => true;`

it will work

Comment: For some reason this isn't working for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and it turned out to be something to do with the fact I was (accidentally) calling `base.IsValid(value, validationContext)` within my custom ValidationAttribute. e.g.

```cs
protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext) 
{
    if ((int)value == 100 
    {
        return base.IsValid(value, validationContext);
    } 
    else return ValidationResult.Success;
}
```

In the scenario were `value == 100` was true and the call went into `base.IsValid(value, validationContext)`, this was causing an *additional* call to my custom validation, and in the second call `validationContext` was null.

I managed to fix this by simply removing the call to `base.IsValid(value, validationContext)`, which was fine for me (I never intended to make this call - it was leftover from the auto-generate code when using intellisense to override the method). However I imagine there may be some cases where you do actually want/need to call the base implementation. I dont know what you would do to solve the error in these cases.