# mvc2 data annotations extensions EqualTo

Tags: asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

I've been using [Data Annotations Extensions](http://dataannotationsextensions.org) for a while now. I want to use the EqualTo attribute but ran into an null reference exception.

Here is the model:

```
   [Required(ErrorMessage = "Password is required.")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please confirm your password.")]
    [EqualTo("Password",ErrorMessage="Your passwords do not match.")]
    public string PasswordConfirm { get; set; }
```

If I remove the EqualTo attribute the post is successful, but with the EqualTo I get a null reference exception. Can anyone suggest a reason why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use CompareAttribute: [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "Your passwords do not match.")]

Comment: unless I'm mistaken isn't the CompareAttribute in MVC3 not MVC2?

Comment: Good point, jumped in there without reading the "mvc2" at the beginning on the question :P

Comment: no problem... looking at the source it appears ValidationContext is null. signature looks like this:protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)

Comment: found this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5408658/validation-context-is-always-null) Looks like ValidationContext is also part of MVC3?

Comment: Found this which might help with MVC2 based comparing by creating a custom attribute: http://www.dotnetguy.co.uk/post/2010/01/09/property-matching-with-data-annotations

Comment: thanks for the link... after looking into this further... the app is targeting .net 4 but ValidationContext was enhanced in MVC3 which is why I got the null exception. the MVC2 comparing article suggested does address the need to compare, but does not use data annotations extensions. not a big deal for me, but might be for someone else.